# MySQL query or procedure for inserting new records simultaneously when updating/deleting existing records

Tags: mysql, sql-update, sql-insert, simultaneous, sql-delete

How would you try to insert and simultaneously update or delete existing records?

Let's say I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `components` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `component` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `x` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `y` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `parent_id` int DEFAULT NOT NULL,
  `state` char(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

I know a simple upsert statement in mysql

```
INSERT INTO components (id, component, x, y, parent_id) VALUES
(1, 2, 0, 0, 1),
(2, 1, 0, 1, 1),
(3, 7, 1, 1, 2)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
component = values(component),
x = values(x), 
y = values(y);
```

Now I also want to delete a component if the id is missing. Any ideas how to accomplish this or should I rather write a procedure?

Nah forget this. I don't think this is possible (I don't want to make it complicated for my self). I'll think I just delete all old records first and insert all as new values... This solution is not good but if anyone else has a suggestion feel free to give me some options.

Triggers won't work also:

```
delimiter |

CREATE TRIGGER update_state BEFORE UPDATE ON components
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
IF new.ID IS NULL THEN # if id is missing set to old
   SET NEW.state = 'old';
else
   SET NEW.state = 'new'; # if id is present set to new
END IF;
END;
|
delimiter ;


delimiter |
CREATE TRIGGER insert_state BEFORE INSERT ON components
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  SET NEW.state = 'new';
END;
|
delimiter ;
```

Any ideas how I make these 3 queries to one procodure? I need to give an array of objects to the procedure (maybe I can do this with json/xml to pass as a parameter?)

```
UPDATE components SET state = 'old' WHERE parent_id = 2;

INSERT INTO components (id, component, x, y, parent_id) VALUES
(1, 1, 0, 0, 2),
(2, 5, 1, 0, 2),
(3, 6, 0, 1, 2),
(4, 7, 1, 1, 2)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
component = values(component)

DELETE FROM components WHERE parent_id = 2 and state = 'old';
```

Comment: Another thing you could do is mark all rows as 'old' (that is, set a value in a new column), then perform your `INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`, setting all affected rows to 'new'. Afterwards, `DELETE FROM tiles WHERE state='old'`.

Comment: Hmmm, could a trigger help me to mark them first as old? Thanks for the advice. I think this might work.

Comment: You want to do this in one SQL statement?

Comment: Not necessary, maybe just use a procedure, don't think trigger is going to work also.

Comment: A trigger won't work because MySQL triggers fire once per row. Setting them all would reset to 'old' the rows you've already inserted. But I don't think that would work anyway, IIRC you can't update in a trigger the same table for which the trigger is firing. I would just do this as two SQL statements from my app. I don't like MySQL stored procedures.

Comment: How to do in 2 queries? I use 3 now. If the parent lets says sets the size 100x100 for x and y, would I just fill the database with useless components? and just update so I don't have to do deletions? Or rather not and just do it like the above and only insert the components that have a value to my parent and delete old unused components?